# Indirection from func() to __func()

Tags: c, function

Quoting a code snippet :

```
/**
 * list_add - add a new entry

 * @new: new entry to be added
 * @head: list head to add it after
 *
 * Insert a new entry after the specified head.
 * This is good for implementing stacks.
 */

static inline void list_add(struct list_head *new, struct list_head *head)
{
    __list_add(new, head, head->next);
}
```

I have seen similar code in several different programs, especially those manipulating data structures. What is the usual intention in adding this extra level of indirection - why can't the code inside __list_add be put inside list_add ?

Answer (score 3):

If you copy code, it will make maintenance harder. In this example, the extra level of indirection hides the parameter next. It will provide a function with just 2 parameters rather than 3.

If the code inside the __list_add() is copied, it needs to be copied to multiple places. If then the list mechanism is changed somewhat, all of these places need to be updated too, or bugs will start to pop-up (i.e. a FIFO and LIFO implementation of a list show different behavior).

There is always a tradeoff; another level of indirection also adds complexity and possibly overhead, as opposed to duplicating lines of code or having lots of parameters in the API.

Comment: +1 for spotting that list_add takes two and __list_add takes three parameters.

Answer (score 2):

It's about code reuse, and avoiding duplication.

`__list_add()` contains code that is useful in more situations than just this one, and can be shared between several different functions.

Sharing code like this has several advantages:

- If there's a bug in `__list_add()` and you fix it, all the functions that use it get the fix.
- If `__list_add()` gets an enhancement (eg. you make it faster) all the functions get faster.
- There's only one place to look when you want to see how items are added to lists.

Answer (score 0):

It can.

However, there are probably other public entries that can share the code in `__list_add()`. eg, there may be a `push()` or an `insert_head()` or something like that.

NOTE: If this is C++ then you might want to rethink calling your variables `new`, as this is a reserved word.

Comment: This is apparently not C++, see the struct qualifier, completely redundant in C++.

Answer (score 0):

__list_add will be intended as a "private" internal function which might have multiple uses internally. The public facing list_add is there as a convenient wrapper around it.

Answer (score 0):

This wrapper is `inline`. If you added the body of `__List_add`, that too would be inlined. The apaprent goal is to just inline the pushing of the extra `head->next` argument and nothing else.

Comment: `inline` does not guarantee inlining.

Comment: Indeed, but the lack of guarantees is not relevant here. And my response would become unreasonable long if I had to explain all details, such as how compilers could inline half of a function

Answer (score 0):

That function comes from the linux kernel.
It belongs to the generic list implementation:

Take a look: [`__list_add()`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.30/include/linux/list.h#L40)

`__list_add()` is used in many places: e.g. `list_add()` which adds an element at a list head, `list_add_tail()` which adds an element at list tail... It can also be used to insert an element at a given position.

Answer (score 0):

It is also common to define an wrapper function for recursive functions so the initial parameters are set correctly.

See binary search on wikipedia for [Recursion (computer science)](http://tinyurl.com/mbx4rd)

Answer (score 0):

Could also be to keep binary compatibility. you have an indirection that allows to keep the ABI invariant.

From http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html

> When a new version of a library is
>   binary-incompatible with the old one
>   the soname needs to change. In C,
>   there are four basic reasons that a
>   library would cease to be binary
>   compatible:
>
> 1. The behavior of a function changes so that it no longer meets its
>      original specification,
> 2. Exported data items change (exception: adding optional items to
>      the ends of structures is okay, as
>      long as those structures are only
>      allocated within the library).
> 3. An exported function is removed.
> 4. The interface of an exported function changes.